# Passing properties to a form before the form is displayed

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an Access user form that I'm opening as a new instance of the form class.
For the example there's no controls on the form - just a blank form.

The form is called `Form2` and the code behind the form is:

```
Private pSomeProperty As String

Public Property Let SomeProperty(Value As String)
    pSomeProperty = Value
End Property

Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Me.Caption = pSomeProperty
End Sub
```

I have another form called `Form1`.  This contains a single button called `Command0`.
The code behind this form is:

```
Dim frm As Form_Form2

Private Sub Command0_Click()

    Set frm = New Form_Form2
    
    With frm
        .SomeProperty = "My New Caption"
        .Visible = True
    End With
    
End Sub
```

What I'm hoping to happen is the form caption reads "My New Caption" when the form opens.
What happens is the form opens with the caption "Form2".

If I add a button to Form2 with the following code then the caption changes when I press it.

```
Private Sub Command2_Click()
    Me.Caption = pSomeProperty
End Sub
```

The order of events when opening a form is
[Open > Load > Resize > Activate > Current](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/order-of-events-for-database-objects-e76fbbfe-6180-4a52-8787-ce86553682f9#bm3)

Activate didn't seem to fire when I checked, but either way `Set frm = New Form_Form2` fires these events before any properties are passed to the form.

If I use the code below it works, but I'm left using the default instance of the form.
How do I pass properties to a form so I can use them before the form is displayed?
I'm sure I've done this before, but it's been so long I can't figure it out now.

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:="Form2", OpenArgs:="My New Caption"
End Sub  

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.Caption = OpenArgs()
End Sub
```

Comment: Try moving `Me.Caption = pSomeProperty` to the OnLoad event.

Comment: @Gustav I tried many events - all the ones mentioned that fire when form loads and opens.  After them I tried any that sounded like they might work - On Got Focus, On Dirty,

Comment: @FaneDuru It's an Access form.  UserForm is Excel. `Form_Load()` is what the VBE gives you when select the event from the drop-downs or create the event directly from the form.  I've tried `Activate`.

Comment: You can use `UserForm` in Access, too, even if not present in the default list of classes to be inserted. I thought you try using such a form... I tested un such a `UserForm` and it works only on `Activate` event. I will delete my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
Set frm = New Form_Form2
```

The `New` keyword will create the form object and fire any opening events e.g. `Form_Load()` but the property assignment `.SomeProperty = "My New Caption"` has not taken place yet.

So the event fires, but the property value is null.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.Caption = pSomeProperty
End Sub
```

To confirm try the below:

```
Private pSomeProperty As String

Public Property Let SomeProperty(Value As String)
    pSomeProperty = Value
    Caption = Value
End Property
```

Comment: Thanks, and for @Gustav who gave the same answer.  I'd realised all the events were firing when I created the object, but couldn't think how to do it.  I haven't updated the caption in the `Let` property as that should just deal with receiving the value.  Instead I created a Public procedure in the class called UpdateCaption and called that after setting the property and before making the form visible.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is, that the property is not set until after the OnCurrent event.

So, use the `Let` of the property:

```vb
Public Property Let SomeProperty(Value As String)
    pSomeProperty = Value
    Me.Caption = pSomeProperty
End Property
```